# Issues enabling Windows Hello for Business via GPO for facial recognition login

Tags: windows, group-policy

Trying to enable Windows Hello for Business across our domain for facial rec login. I went through and read the latest article from Microsoft on doing this (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-cert-trust-policy-settings) but I am still running into problems.

When I open up Sign-in options, the "set up" button for facial recognition is greyed out and under "PIN" I'm getting "Something went wrong. Try again later."

I cannot find any other option that would be helpful for enabling this in GPME.

[image: Current GPO configuration]

[image: Sign in options]

Client PC is running Win10 Ver 1809, Domain Controller is running Win Server 2012 R2 Ver 6.3

Answer (score 1):

According to the article below, Windows Hello for Business and the PIN are two different things.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3201940/can-t-configure-a-pin-when-convenience-pin-and-hello-for-business-poli

If you enable both GPO (Windows Hello for Business and PIN), neither will work. You need to enable one or the other. Therefore, my suggestion, following the article above would be to disable the PIN-related GPOs, and only leave the ones for Windows Hello for Business and the biometrics enabled.

Comment: Unless I am misreading or misunderstanding, I don't think you can allow or disallow one or the other. From the article I posted this is towards the bottom: "Currently, Windows does not provide granular policy setting that enable you to disable specific modalities of biometrics such as allow facial recognition, but disallow fingerprint." This to me sounds like I need to have both PIN and Facial allowed even though we won't be utilizing PIN yet (if ever.)

Comment: No you're right, it was my mistake. From my understanding of this part:

"The default Windows Hello for Business enables users to enroll and use biometrics."

You don't need to set the biometrics-related GPOs at all. Simply enabling the Windows Hello for Business ones should do the trick.